# RestKit: serializedObjectForMIMEType failed with error

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm trying to get the JSON format string from my custom object by using RestKit.

Here is my code:

```
@interface MyPhoneModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *number;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *tag;

@end

@interface MyContactModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *phoneList;

@end

- (NSString *)jsonString:(MyContactModel *)contact
{
    RKObjectMapping *phoneMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyPhoneModel class]];
    [phoneMapping mapKeyPath:@"number" toAttribute:@"number"];
    [phoneMapping mapKeyPath:@"tag" toAttribute:@"tag"];

    RKObjectMapping *contactMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyContactModel class]];
    [contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
    [contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"phoneList" toRelationship:@"phoneList" withMapping:phoneMapping];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *json = [[RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:contact mapping:contactMapping] serializedObjectForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON error:&error];
    return json;
}
```

But when I call this method, it failed with error.
**Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unable to serialize object class MyPhoneModel." UserInfo=0x898c400 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to serialize object class MyPhoneModel.**

So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this link :
[Examples of using](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/Specs/ObjectMapping/RKObjectSerializerSpec.m)

In every example I could find the mapping is done with [NSDictionary class] or [NSMutableDictionary class]

So maybe like this :

```
RKObjectMapping* phoneMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class] ];
[phoneMapping  mapAttributes:@"number", @"tag", nil];

 RKObjectMapping *contactMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
[contactMapping mapKeyPath:@"phoneList" toRelationship:@"phoneList" withMapping:phoneMapping];
```

You want this serialized string for using with RKClient ?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted!